# Applying VBA code to each cell to fomat another cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm still learning how to write VBA and it is quite challenging. Hope someone can help me.

I want to highlight cell in column `D:E`,`G` when i select "Add CCG/CC/PCG/PC" in my column `B`. But i want to apply this from `B15:B114`. when i select it in `B15`, `D14:E15`,`G15` should be highlighted. if i select `B18` then `D18`,`E18` & `G18` should be highlighted & so on. i am only able to do it in one row but how can i apply it to my desired range without doing it one by one.
thanks in advance

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Range("B15").Value = "Add CCG/CC/PCG/PC" Then

    Range("D15:E15,G15").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

    ElseIf Range("B15").Value = "" Then
    Range("D15:E15,G15").Select

        With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlNone
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0

    End With

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you looked into [conditionnal formatting](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/conditional-formatting-6b6f7c2a-5d62-45a1-8f67-584a76776d67)?

Comment: cybernetic.nomad - Yes, the problem with the conditional formatting is that it works with some cells then suddenly wont with another, that's why im trying my luck with VBA code

Comment: That should not be the case. I suggest you ask another question about that. For your VBA, you will probably want to loop through your rows -- a search should reveal several questions (and answers!) about that

Comment: "_when i select it in B15, D14:E15,G15 should be highlighted_"  I take it that should be `D15:E15`?

Answer (score 0):

**To do it with conditional formatting only:**

- Select cells `D15:E15, G15`
- Select *New Rule* in `Conditional Formatting`.

  - Select *Use a formula to determine which cells to format*
  - Add the formula `=$B15="Add CCG/CC/PCG/PC"`
    **Note** - no `$` before the row number.
  - Set the desired format.
- Drag `D15:E15, G15` down to `D114:E115, G114`.

**To do it with VBA:**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    'Check the changed cell is in the range B15:B114.
    'Not Is Nothing = it is something...
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B15:B114")) Is Nothing Then
        With Target
            If .Value = "Add CCG/CC/PCG/PC" Then
                'Target is the changed cell.  Offset by 2 columns is column D.
                'Resize by 2 columns is columns D:E.
                'Union with Offset 5 columns (column G) to return cells to change.
                With Union(.Offset(, 2).Resize(, 2), .Offset(, 5)).Interior
                    .Pattern = xlSolid
                    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
                End With
            Else
                With Union(.Offset(, 2).Resize(, 2), .Offset(, 5)).Interior
                    .Pattern = xlNone
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
                End With
            End If
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

Further reading:

- [Worksheet Change Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change)
- [Intersect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.intersect)
- [Union](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.union)
- [Offset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset)
- [Resize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize)
- [With...End With Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/with-end-with-statement)

Comment: Thank you everyone, i will try the code provided too